# How to get property from gradle.properties

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

If I set a property in my `gradle.properties` file using the command line like so:

`gradle build -Dproperty=myString`

and in my Android project have a `configuration.properties` in my resources directory, how can I get `configuration.properties` to read the new property from the `gradle.properties` file?

I've tried the following setup:

**gradle.properties**

```
property=defaultString
anotherProperty=defaultBoolean
```

**configuration.properties**

```
myProperty=@property@
```

---

**POTENTIAL SOLUTION 1**

*Using a `configuration.properties` file for each flavor.*

The per-flavor resources sounded like a great idea, but I wanted to have a default list in `main`, and only override the properties needed. I have a lot of properties, and some flavors would only need to override one. So this does work, but is not ideal.

---

**POTENTIAL SOLUTION 2**

*Using `buildConfigField` to pass what I need to the Java code.*

The problem here is that I have two modules: `app` and `api` - where `api` is a dependency of `app`. Setting a `buildConfigField` in the `app` `build.gradle` lets me access them in the `app` code, but I would also need to access it from the `api` module.

Comment: I don't think you can. What's the use case? (By the way, `-D` isn't setting a (project) property in `gradle.properties`; it's setting a system property for the Gradle JVM. The command line equivalent to setting a property in `gradle.properties` is `-P`.)

Comment: Thanks for the response Peter. I currently read from the `configuration.properties` in the source code of the project (from the main app module, and a seperate api module). For example, I have a property called `marketplace` which swaps out certain things in the code depending on which variation of the app I'm building. I actually want to be able to configure these from the app's `productFlavors`, as this is what I had planned to use for the different build variations - but cant seem to set them there either.

Answer (score 0):

To vary property values per flavor, you can use per-flavor resource files. For more information, check the [Android Gradle plugin docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors).

PS: If the property values are only used to activate different parts of the codebase, consider using per-flavor code instead.

Comment: So is there no way to access the `gradle.properties` file from the java code?

Comment: You might be able to implement this *somehow*, e.g. by generating a resource file from `gradle.properties`. However, this is not a first-class feature, and you wouldn't be able to vary the values by flavor (there is just one `gradle.properties` file, not one per flavor). On the other hand, per-flavor resources (or per-flavor code) seems like a straightforward and idiomatic solution to your problem.

Comment: The per-flavor resources sounded like a great idea, but I wanted to have a default list in `main`, and only override the properties needed. I have a lot of properties, and some flavors would only need to override one. I'll add this and more in the form of an edit to the question.

Comment: Resources get merged, so this should be possible. Check the docs to be sure.

Comment: I just tested it in an example app, and it doesn't merge :(

Comment: Check the docs on *how* resources get merged. There should be a solution.